# tbb::combinable::local() is too slow

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

I've got a worker function executed in parallel. This worker function is calling tbb::combineable::local() pretty often and it turns out to be very slow.
I think I need to implement my own combinable.

I would like to preallocate in every MyCombineable a vector of the contained element and access it via some integer derived from the thread-id. This index can be determined once inside the worker function and passed to every call to combineable::local().
But in order to do so, I would need to know the number of threads in tbb's thread pool and their thread-ids.

Or any other idea?

Comment: enumerable_thread_specific has a template argument that let's you essentially use thread-local storage, albeit in that mode it consumes one TLS key per instance.  Can you say more about the use case?  Perhaps tbb::parallel_reduce is more appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

rather than implement your own .local method, have you tried caching the call as a reference and doing the lookup less often, also perhaps working on more than one item at once per task.

To see the threads as they come in you can implement a task_scheduler_observer in tbb before you schedule any concurrent work then warm up the scheduler by scheduling some tasks to see the thread ids if you want to pre-allocate the thread ids.

You can also try implementing something of your own on top of concurrent_unordered_map to get the thread id and use it to store an index into a vector, but I suspect you will find the cost of looking up the thread is still high if you are noticing the lookup costs of combinable.

Comment: I only call local() once for any one object.

Answer (score 0):

With the code below the local() function does not show up in profiling anymore.
One needs to retrieve the index for the current thread once (using getTid() -- see below) and then one can call the fast local() implementation for different objects by passing the index.

```
// *s_iNumberOfThreads is passed to tbb::task_scheduler_init()
// and represents the number of threads
// still don't know how to get the number of threads in tbb's threadpool
template<typename T>
struct Combinable
{       std::vector<T*, tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<T*> > m_s;
        tbb::cache_aligned_allocator<T> m_sAllocator;
        __forceinline void allocate(void)
        {       try 
                {       for (std::size_t i = 0, iMax = m_s.size(); i < iMax; ++i)
                                m_s[i] = m_sAllocator.allocate(1);
                } catch (...)
                {       deallocate();
                        throw;
                }
        }
        __forceinline void deallocate(void)
        {       for (std::size_t i = 0, iMax = m_s.size(); i < iMax; ++i)
                        if (m_s[i])
                                m_sAllocator.deallocate(m_s[i], 1);
        }
        __forceinline Combinable(const Combinable&_r)
                :m_s(*s_iNumberOfThreads)
        {       allocate();
                for (std::size_t i = 0, iMax = m_s.size(); i < iMax; ++i)
                        *m_s[i] = *_r.m_s[i];
        }
        __forceinline Combinable &operator=(const Combinable&_r)
        {       if (&_r != this)
                        for (std::size_t i = 0, iMax = m_s.size(); i < iMax; ++i)
                                *m_s[i] = *_r.m_s[i];
                return *this;
        }
        __forceinline Combinable(void)
                :m_s(*s_iNumberOfThreads)
        {       allocate();
                clear();
        }
        __forceinline ~Combinable(void)
        {       deallocate();
        }
        __forceinline T &local(const unsigned int _i)
        {       return *m_s[_i];
        }
        __forceinline const T &local(const unsigned int _i) const
        {       return *m_s[_i];
        }
        template<typename C>
        __forceinline T combine(const C &_r) const
        {       T d(0.0);
                for (std::size_t i = 0, iMax = m_s.size(); i < iMax; ++i)
                        d = _r(d, *m_s[i]);
                return d;
        }
        __forceinline void clear(void)
        {       for (std::size_t i = 0, iMax = m_s.size(); i < iMax; ++i)
                        *m_s[i] = 0.0;
        }
};  
static tbb::combinable<unsigned int> s_sThreadId((unsigned int)~0);
static long s_iMaxThreadId;
    // this function returns the index to be passed to local()
__forceinline unsigned int getTid(void)
{       unsigned int &i = s_sThreadId.local();
        if (i == ~0)
                // could use tbb::atomic here -- but it is difficult to
                // initialize
                // or even better std::atomic 
                // (but I cannot use this currently 
                // due to compatibility reason)
#ifdef _MSC_VER
                return i = _InterlockedIncrement(&s_iMaxThreadId) - 1;
#else
                return i = __sync_add_and_fetch(&s_iMaxThreadId, 1) - 1;
#endif
        else
                return i;
}
```